# DICE loss too low but no overlap between prediction and label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dice, loss

I am trying to achieve the segmentation of the bone on the cross sectional area of MRI images with the Unet I found here https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet. The label is a binary png image which I intend to compare to my prediction. For the frames, I wrote my own data loader for my DICOM MRI files

I am using the following dice loss in keras

```
def DiceLoss(targets, inputs, smooth=1e-6):

#flatten label and prediction tensors
inputs = K.flatten(inputs)
targets = K.flatten(targets)

intersection = K.sum(K.dot(targets, inputs))
dice = (2*intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(targets) + K.sum(inputs) + smooth)
return 1 - dice
```

I have seen it in kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch
among other similar implementations in Keras that I found out there.

But the DICE loss is always too small (10^-4) even though there is no overlap between the prediction and the label. Why is this? should I first convert my prediction to  a binary mask? if so, How can I do this in keras? I tried to convert `targets` to a numpy array by doing targets.numpy() and then apply a threshold, but it throws a "tensor does not have attribute numpy" error. Do you have any other idea?

thank you

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly where your issue is, because there could be a lot of different sources. The one thing that I'm considering is that from past experience working with biomedical data, class imbalance is a *huge* problem. If there is a class imbalance, it is very likely your model will learn a simple, suboptimal solution. Try training with batches of even distributed classes

Comment: Yes there is a class imbalance, the bone is just a small dot. That's why I tried to use the DICE loss to see if it was better, shouldn't the DICE loss be 1 if theres no intersection between my prediction and the label?